# How to run bin/spark-submit in java code?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've been learning Spark recently. I usually submit Spark Job through command line. For Example:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master local[8] \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  100
```

However, I want to run spark-submit in Java code, like
`SparkResult result = sc.submit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the executable with [`java.lang.Runtime.exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29).

Or from the [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html), this seems to be your example:

```
int count = spark.parallelize(makeRange(1, NUM_SAMPLES)).filter(new Function<Integer, Boolean>() {
  public Integer call(Integer i) {
    double x = Math.random();
    double y = Math.random();
    return x*x + y*y < 1;
  }
}).count();
System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4 * count / NUM_SAMPLES);
```