# How to execute spark-submit in Java with Scala .jar provided?

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, jar

I have several `Spark` big data applications written in `Scala`. These applications have their other version written in `R`.

I also have a web server application written in `Java`. This is provided as API for the web GUI. The purpose is to enable GUI to execute these applications and choose the version: `R` or `Spark`. I managed to call the `R` code from the `Java` API and get the result to `JSON`. But now it seems to be quite complicated to execute the `Spark` programs.

Until now, I was able to merge one of the `Scala` .jar file with the `Java` API with `Maven`. I do this by placing my `Spark` program as a local repository in `pom.xml` so that the `Scala` code is included in the final .jar package. I also mentioned `Scala` and `breeze` library as dependencies in the `pom.xml`. And when I try to send a request with the API, of course it throws an error saying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$`. By this point, I realize that it was because I haven't mentioned `Spark` library in `Maven` dependencies, but then I think I've been doing it wrong, since `Spark` applications are generally run by executing `spark-submit` command in terminal.

So now what I'm thinking is putting the `Java` API .jar and `Scala` .jar in one folder, and then executing `spark-submit` from inside of `Java` API .jar, targeting the `Scala` .jar. Is this even correct? And how to execute the `spark-submit` from Java code? Does it have to be using `Runtime.exec()` as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354165/how-to-run-bin-spark-submit-in-java-code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SparkLauncher` can be used to submit the spark code(written in scala with precomplied jar `scala.jar` placed at certain location) from the Java Api code.

The [saprk documentaion](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html) for using SparkLauncher recommends the below way to submit the spark job pro-grammatically from inside Java Applications. Add the below code in your Java Api code.

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkAppHandle;
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;

   public class MyLauncher {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       SparkAppHandle handle = new SparkLauncher()
         .setAppResource("/my/scala.jar")
         .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
         .setMaster("local")
         .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
         .startApplication();
       // Use handle API to monitor / control application.
     }
   }
```